# Writing pcap to Buffer with Scapy

Tags: python, buffer, scapy, pcap, bytesio

I'm having trouble writing a pcap to a file buffer, it's important I do not touch disk for these pcap captures and yes they must be live.

```
sudo scapy
>>> import io
>>> cap = sniff(timeout=30)
>>> buf = io.BytesIO()
>>> wrpcap(buf, cap)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/utils.py", line 524, in wrpcap
    with PcapWriter(filename, *args, **kargs) as fdesc:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/utils.py", line 682, in __init__
    self.f = [open,gzip.open][gz](filename,append and "ab" or "wb", gz and 9 or bufsz)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _io.BytesIO found
```

This usually happens when you do open(None), is this a bug in the PcapWriter function in Scapy Utils?

I've also tried this with: `buf.seek(0)` before writing and it still fails.

Comment: I checked in code - `wrpcap` expects filename. You can't use any buffer.

Comment: Wonder if there is anyway I could get the pcap data to a buffer hmm.

Comment: if in `utils.py` you could change line `self.f = [open,gzip.open]...` into `self.f = your_buffer` then probaly you could get `pcap` in memory. You can get `wrpcap` code and write own version with own `self.f`.

Comment: Yeah, I coud try modifying the `utils.py` file however I discovered I can do this: `buf = io.BytesIO() for i in range(0, len(cap)-1): buf.write(str(cap[i]))` the only downside is it's all raw packet data and not pcap format. 'text2pcap' from the WireShark utilities is proving difficult with that data however. So yeah you can steam out the data as a buffer but seems like only raw packet data and not in the pcap format.

Comment: btw. shorter and more pythonic `for x in cap: buf.write(str(x))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got code from `scapy` (`utils.py`) and created `memwrpcap` which can write to `io.BytesIO`.

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
memwrpcap(buf, cap)
```

(after writing it doesn't close buffer and you can move to beginning to read from buffer.)

After that I used standard `open()` and `write()` to save data from `io.BytesIO` and compared this file with file created with `wrpcap`

```
diff -c test-std.pcap test-mem.pcap
```

and it seems they are identical so `io.BytesIO` has data in pcap format.

Full code - `memwrpcam`, `MemoryPcapWriter` and code which I used to test it.

```
#
# from: scapy/utils.py
#

from scapy.all import *

def memwrpcap(filename, pkt, *args, **kargs):
    """Write a list of packets to a pcap file
    gz: set to 1 to save a gzipped capture
    linktype: force linktype value
    endianness: "<" or ">", force endianness"""

    # use MemoryPcapWriter instead of PcapWriter
    with MemoryPcapWriter(filename, *args, **kargs) as fdesc:
        fdesc.write(pkt)


class MemoryPcapWriter(PcapWriter):
    """A stream PCAP writer with more control than wrpcap()"""
    def __init__(self, filename, linktype=None, gz=False, endianness="", append=False, sync=False):
        """
        linktype: force linktype to a given value. If None, linktype is taken
                  from the first writter packet
        gz: compress the capture on the fly
        endianness: force an endianness (little:"<", big:">"). Default is native
        append: append packets to the capture file instead of truncating it
        sync: do not bufferize writes to the capture file
        """

        self.linktype = linktype
        self.header_present = 0
        self.append=append
        self.gz = gz
        self.endian = endianness
        self.filename=filename
        self.sync=sync
        bufsz=4096
        if sync:
            bufsz=0

        # use filename or file-like object 
        if isinstance(self.filename, str):
            self.f = [open,gzip.open][gz](filename,append and "ab" or "wb", gz and 9 or bufsz)
        else: # file-like object 
            self.f = filename

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tracback):
        self.flush()
        if isinstance(self.filename, str):
            self.close() # don't close file-like object


# --- main ---

#
# run script with sudo
#
# compare results (on Linux)
#    diff -s test-std.pcap test-mem.pcap
#

from scapy.all import *

import io

cap = sniff(timeout=5)

# save to pcap file
wrpcap('test-std.pcap', cap)

# save to buffer
buf = io.BytesIO()
memwrpcap(buf, cap)

# move to beginning and save to file
#print('current position:', buf.tell())
buf.seek(0)
#print('current position:', buf.tell())

with open('test-mem.pcap', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(buf.read())
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot in a little bit: i was able to use a file buffer to write each packet as raw hex then take those and convert them into a useful pcap doing: `for f in *.hex; do od -Ax -tx1 -v $f >> cap.dump; done && text2pcap -n cap.dump cap.pcap` the problem I had reassembling the data was that text2pcap needs to know the length of each packet before it can be properly processed. I'll give this here a shot here later, if it works this should be made into a pull request to scapy.

Comment: As an additional note, it might be because of my version of `utils.py` is older if anyone has issues making this work just change with `MemoryPcapWriter(filename, *args, **kargs) as fdesc: fdesc.write(pkt)` to `MemoryPcapWriter(filename, *args, **kargs).write(pkt)` Other than that this works like a charm, are you going to create a pull request of this for the scapy project?

Comment: I checked  the newest code in repo and it was added 8 March. Now you can use `PcapWriter()` instead of `wrpcap()` : `buf = io.BytesIO() ; PcapWriter(buf).write(cap)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use Scapy's latest version, it works out of the box:

```
Welcome to Scapy (2.3.3)
>>> import io
>>> cap = sniff(timeout=30)
>>> buf = io.BytesIO()
>>> wrpcap(buf, cap)
>>>
```

If you need to keep `buf` open, just do:

```
Welcome to Scapy (2.3.3)
>>> import io
>>> cap = sniff(timeout=30)
>>> buf = io.BytesIO()
>>> PcapWriter(buf).write(cap)
>>> buf.seek(0)
0L
>>> rdpcap(buf)
<No name: TCP:736 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>
```

Comment: just I found it in the code on GitHub :) And It seems you add this modification :)

Comment: I did, merged 7+ months ago however, so that's not really new ;)

Comment: Looks like i'll have to get the Github version of scapy Kali must be outdated lol!

Comment: Yeah Kali is outdated, I've tried wrpcap however still need to have the buffer open afterwards to manipulate it. The second set of code with the newer version however works fine.